# Eliminating cross in a python matrix (list of list)

Tags: python, list, matrix

Let us suppose we have an input square matrix so done:

```
    test_matrix7x7_v01 = [[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                          [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                          [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                          [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                          [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                          [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                          [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]]
```

and let's suppose I would like to delete a "cross" of the matrix (for example the first row and the first column).

I wrote this function that works properly:

```
def eliminate_cross(_comp_matrix,i,j):
    size = len(_comp_matrix[0])
    print("eliminating cross")
    matrix_copy = deepcopy(_comp_matrix)
    # print("deleting row")
    matrix_copy.remove(_comp_matrix[j])
    # print("deleting column")
    for h in range(size-1):
        del matrix_copy[h][j]
    return matrix_copy
```

and, using the input reported above, gives:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]]
```

**Question**: is there a proper way of doing this operation? a smart way or a one-line built-in instruction?

Comment: If you used numpy it would be significantly more efficient: `np.array(_comp_matrix[1:, 1:])`

Comment: Use `del _comp_matrix[0]` instead of `remove`.

Comment: @MZ yes, right. But this means also that I should convert list-of-list --> np.array --> list-of-list. This is a solution, right. Which one is the best? are there other ways for it?

Comment: @AlexHall right. However, my problem is with the for loop :)

Comment: Depending on the larger problem you should maybe use only numpy. But if you have to work with lists, you're going to need loops, and this is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possibility:

```
def remove_cross(A,i,j):
    return [row[:j] + row[(j+1):] for k,row in enumerate(A) if k != i]
```

Comment: How about splitting `A` like you split `row`?

Comment: @superbrain That would have a pleasing symmetry, but I don't think that would be as efficient since it would create two new lists in memory just to iterate over them.

Comment: Yeah but you do the same for every row, which is n times as much.

Comment: Hi @JohnColeman, can I ask you where can I read about the "strategy" used to write this kind of lines in Python? Thank you for your patience

Comment: @Leos313 There is a recent book called "Python One-Liners" by Christain Mayer which seems promising. Beyond that, just subscribe to the `python` tag on Stack Overflow and see how questions are typically answered. An interesting phenomenon is how often essentially the same (or in some cases exactly the same) answer is given by two or more people within a few minutes of the question being asked. I've learned a great deal about Python just by following the tag.

Answer (score 1):

This is at least a bit better...

```
def eliminate_cross(A, i, j):
    A = deepcopy(A)
    del A[i]
    for row in A:
        del row[j]
    return A
```

Comment: sure it is! however, I am looking for a kind of one-line solution. I am thinking to reconvert all the list-of-lists in numpy array

Comment: @Leos313 `[*zip(*[*zip(*_comp_matrix[1:])][1:])]`.

Comment: @Leos313 It's really ugly and can't delete middle rows/columns.

Comment: yes it is! if you change the 0 with other number you can generalize the function!! I did not test, but it was my original idea when I wrote the question and the function in the question

Comment: @Leos313 It doesn't have a zero. What are you talking about? :-)

Comment: del matrix_copy[0] first line, del matrix_copy[1] second line and so on. The same for the column

Comment: @Leos313 Huh? That's already the answer. We were talking about my silly oneliner.

Comment: But yeah, I followed the other guys in switching to reasonable parameters now.

Answer (score 1):

What about an option for more than one row and col to be eliminated?

```
def eliminate(matrix, rows, cols):
    return [[c for j, c in enumerate(r) if j not in cols] for i,r in enumerate(matrix) if i not in rows]

print(eliminate(test_matrix7x7_v01, (0,), (0,)))
```